# LuaLaTeX and makenote

Tags: luatex, koma-script

Under TeXLive 2016 i have an problem with following code:

```
\documentclass[mpinclude=true]{scrbook}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\usepackage{scrlayer-notecolumn}


\begin{document}
This is \makenote{margin note} test.
\end{document}
```

It works with LaTeX or XeLaTeX but LuaLaTeX throws error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...ue {slncpage}}{\noexpand \number \scr@lastypos 
                                                  }{margin note}}
l.10 This is \makenote{margin note}
                                  test.
```

Comment: That's a bug in scrlayer-notecolumn, a brace is in the wrong place and so the logic is faulty. I have notified the author. Loading luatex85 as suggested by nasser will go around the bug.

Comment: The bug is fixed in KOMA-Script v3.21.2483. This version is available on http://www.komascript.de/node/1801

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this and see if it works for you

```
\documentclass[mpinclude=true]{scrbook}
\IfFileExists{luatex85.sty}{\usepackage{luatex85}}{}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\usepackage{scrlayer-notecolumn}

\begin{document}
This is \makenote{margin note} test.
\end{document}
```